# remove attribution is not a function

Tags: leaflet

Hello guys I'm trying to remove the leaflet logo on the leaflet map but whenever I try to remove the logo using `removeattribution` it says it's not a function. I'm doing it like this `L.removeattribution().addTo(map)`. Please tell me if I'm doing it correctly or is there something wrong in it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `attributionControl` option of `L.Map`:

> Whether the attribution control is added to the map by default.

http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-attributioncontrol

```
new L.Map('container', {
    'attributionControl': false
});
```

If you want to remove it after you've initialized your map you can use the `removeControl` method of `L.Map`:

> Removes the given control from the map.

http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-removecontrol

The attribution control instance is stored as property `attributionControl` of your `L.Map` instance:

```
var map = new L.Map('container');

map.removeControl(map.attributionControl);
```

Comment: Absolutely no problem, it's what we're here for and remember, the [reference guide](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html) is your best friend :)

Answer (score 1):

`removeAttribution` (note the uppercase 'A') is not a static function of `L`, but instead a method of an instance of `L.Control.Attribution`. So the proper way of using that method is first fetching the map's default attribution control:

```
var map = L.map('map');
var control = map.attributionControl;
```

And then call [`removeAttribution`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#control-attribution-removeattribution) with the string you want to remove, like:

```
control.removeAttribution('© OpenStreetMap');
```

Answer (score 1):

If using `react-leaflet`, you can remove attribution by attaching `attributionControl={false}` to the `Map` component:

`<Map attributionControl={false} center={this.props.mapCenter} zoom={this.props.zoom}>`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it at the time of the initialization. try to do it like this.

```
L.Map('container', {
    'attributionControl': false
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add attributionControl prop in MapContainer tag to remove attribution.

`<MapContainer attributionControl={false}>...</MapContainer>`

Answer (score -1):

const mapInstance = L.map("map", {
attributionControl: false,
}).setView([24.9283212, 67.1330418], 12);

this is working for me to remove water marke

Comment: It has been answered several times.